# How to scrape a website with dynamic data

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I would like to web scrape [this site](https://www.quantalys.com/Fonds/Composition/45865), and in particular the graphs that are at the bottom of the page here:
[image]

How can I do this with requests and BeautifulSoup?

I know that I have to do something like this:

```
url = "https://www.quantalys.com/Fonds/Composition/45865" 
api_url = "https://www.quantalys.com/Fonds/GetCompoTableAndGraph" # But there are 4 files named like that!!!
        
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

query = [??????] # I do not know what sort of information to input there
data = {???????} # I do not know what sort of information to input there

data = requests.post(api_url, data=data).json()
graph = json.loads(data['graph']) 
df = pd.DataFrame(graph['graph'])
```

Any help will be great!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scraping dynamic webpage using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71306518/scraping-dynamic-webpage-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `typeCompo` parameter:

```
import requests

api_url = "https://www.quantalys.com/Fonds/GetCompoTableAndGraph"

dfs = {}
for compo in [1, 2, 3, 6]:
    payload = {'ID_Produit': 45865, 'typeCompo': compo}
    data = requests.post(api_url, data=payload).json()
    dfs[compo] = pd.DataFrame(data['graph']['dataProvider'])
```

Output:

```
>>> dfs[1]
             x  Act. Allemagne  Monétaire  Act. Autriche  Act. Belgique  ...  Act. Grèce  Act. Irlande  Act. Italie  Act. Pays-Bas  Act. Portugal
0   01/07/2021            5.71      13.33            0.0           6.07  ...         0.0         20.95          0.0          12.68           1.55
1   01/08/2021           10.13      13.74            0.0           7.70  ...         0.0         19.65          0.0           9.91           0.49
2   01/09/2021            7.22      12.65            0.0           5.33  ...         0.0         19.58          0.0          12.48           0.00
3   01/10/2021            5.56      12.38            0.0           1.74  ...         0.0         14.98          0.0          20.71           0.94
4   01/11/2021            9.29      14.24            0.0           2.06  ...         0.0          6.12          0.0          27.41           0.01
5   01/12/2021           10.16      15.13            0.0           0.01  ...         0.0          3.07          0.0          29.07           1.08
6   01/01/2022            0.00       7.07            0.0           0.00  ...         0.0          2.82          0.0          56.00           0.00
7   01/02/2022            0.00       7.92            0.0           0.00  ...         0.0          1.25          0.0          54.95           0.88
8   01/03/2022            0.00       7.73            0.0           0.00  ...         0.0          0.00          0.0          53.91           2.70
9   01/04/2022            0.00       6.50            0.0           0.00  ...         0.0          0.00          0.0          55.31           3.58
10  01/05/2022            0.00       7.27            0.0           0.00  ...         0.0          0.00          0.0          56.79           1.19
11  01/06/2022            0.00       6.30            0.0           0.00  ...         0.0          0.05          0.0          58.70           1.07
12  01/07/2022            0.00       3.08            0.0           0.00  ...         0.0          0.00          0.0          64.37           1.91
13  01/08/2022            0.00        NaN            0.0           0.00  ...         0.0          0.00          0.0          69.20           2.95
14  01/09/2022            0.00        NaN            0.0           0.00  ...         0.0          0.00          0.0          68.61           2.73
15  01/10/2022            0.00        NaN            0.0           0.01  ...         0.0          0.00          0.0          68.66           1.47
16  01/11/2022            0.00       1.28            0.0           0.00  ...         0.0          0.00          0.0          60.45           4.34
17  01/12/2022            0.00        NaN            0.0           0.00  ...         0.0          0.00          0.0          61.49           4.36
18  01/01/2023            0.00       1.03            0.0           0.00  ...         0.0          0.00          0.0          64.06           1.18
19  01/02/2023            0.00        NaN            0.0           8.55  ...         0.0          0.43          0.0          63.80           0.00
20  01/03/2023            0.00        NaN            0.0           8.66  ...         0.0          1.25          0.0          63.09           0.00
21  01/04/2023            0.00        NaN            0.0           9.96  ...         0.0          2.99          0.0          62.56           0.00
22  01/05/2023            0.00        NaN            0.0          15.35  ...         0.0          3.04          0.0          58.55           0.00
23  01/06/2023            0.00        NaN            0.0          15.61  ...         0.0          3.02          0.0          58.64           0.00
24  01/07/2023            0.00        NaN            0.0           7.86  ...         0.0          0.00          0.0          57.80           0.01

[25 rows x 13 columns]
```